# Is it possible for a tiefling warlock to cast Augury when they are first level?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-creation, warlock, tiefling

I have started running D&D 5e just now, so I do not have an encyclopedic knowledge of character creation options. We played a first session, with half character generation and half low-key play.

One player made a tiefling warlock and said they use their *augury* ability that they have since they are a tiefling. I did not carefully go through their character sheets; players are responsible for that, but I also checked some obvious sources and only found that tieflings get *thaumaturgy* from their race, not *augury*. But maybe there is some variant that gets *augury*, or gets to add *augury* to their spell list, etc. The character is first level.

The player claimed to know the rules but made false claims about them during the session. The player is a stranger to me and the other players. I will, for sure, ask them to show their work at the beginning of the next session, but I would also like to know what the rules actually say.

**Is it possible for a warlock tiefling to have access to the *augury* spell, as a first level character?**

I am most interested in official published (not Unearthed Arcana) WotC material, but if there is notable UA or well-known third party material that allows this, that would also be useful information.

(I do *not*, at the moment, need advice on handling the social situation, and will ask a separate question if it becomes relevant.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Such a character can't cast *augury*, barring some kind of magic item or homebrew

[*Augury*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/augury) is a 2nd-level spell. It is not a tiefling racial spell, as you noted, nor even a warlock spell.

The *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* and *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* add a number of other tiefling variants with different racial spells - but none of them get *augury* as a racial spell, and those racial spells all match the template (spell level and corresponding character level) of the PHB tiefling. (The same is true of the variants originally proposed in [UA: That Old Black Magic](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/07_UA_That_Old_Black_Magic.pdf) and [UA: Fiendish Options](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA_FiendishOptions.pdf).)

There are a number of published warlock patrons across the official 5e books, but none grant *augury* as an option from the subclass expanded spell list, and even if they did, they wouldn't add a 2nd-level spell as an option for the character to learn until the character could cast 2nd-level spells.

If the player claims to know/have access to the spell, ask them where they got it from. I see no means for any 1st-level character to do so without a magic item or some kind of homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

I'd wager it's a misunderstanding of the racial traits. I did find a [5e homebrew augury tiefling](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Ascendant_Tiefling,_Variant_(5e_Race_Variant)), who gets it at level 5 (emphasis mine):

> Radiant Legacy. Instead of Infernal Legacy. You know the light cantrip. When you reach 3rd level, you can cast the healing word spell once and need to finish a long rest before you can cast it again. **When you reach 5th level, you can also cast the augury spell** once and need to finish a long rest before you can cast it again. Wisdom is your spellcasting ability for these spells.

I'd bet whatever source your player is relying on has a similar level requirement he has missed or ignored.

Also, it's worth noting Augury has a material component [(specially marked sticks, bones, or similar tokens worth at least 25 gp)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/augury) which, according to [Sage Advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/03/07/does-the-gnome-need-materials-for-minor-illusion/), is required unless explicitly ignored in the racial trait:

> If a racial trait grants a spell, the trait tells you if you can ignore any of the spell's components.

So even if there was a path to casting it, it's unlikely they'd have the material components.

Comment: But the material components requirement does not matter if they have a focus, right?

Comment: @lucidbrot: Not quite. Material components that don't have a stated cost and aren't consumed can be substituted with a component pouch, or a spellcasting focus if the feature you get the spell from tells you you can use one. (Racial spells don't generally let you substitute the components with a spellcasting focus.) However, if the material components have a stated cost and/or they are consumed, you can't substitute them.

Comment: ...and they should be asking their DM before they use homebrew *anyway*.